# C++ - Char array somehow initializes to wrong size

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, gcc

I am writing a string class from scratch as part of a class assignment, and I am having trouble with writing the substring function. From what I can tell, it has to do with a character array initializing to the wrong size.

From what I can tell, everything else in the string class works beautifully. I am writing this in Qt creator on Ubuntu.

```
string string::substring(unsigned int startIndex, unsigned int endIndex) const {
    if (startIndex >= endIndex) {
        string s;
        return s;
    }
    if (endIndex > length) endIndex = length;

    int rlength = endIndex - startIndex;

    char* r = new char[rlength];

    for (int i = 0; i < rlength; i++) {
    r[i] = chars[i + startIndex];

    }

    string s2(r);
    return s2;
}
```

What I expect to see:

```
"This is a test".substring(0, 4) -> "This"
"This is a test".substring(6, 8) -> "is"
"This is a test".substring(9, 10) -> "a"
```

What I actually see:

```
"This is a test".substring(0, 4) -> "This"
"This is a test".substring(6, 8) -> "is"
"This is a test".substring(9, 10) -> "a�;�"
```

From my own troubleshooting, it looks like r is somehow initialized to a larger size than expected, leaving some garbage after the expected text. Does anyone know why could be happening?

Comment: `string s2(r); return s2;` -- There is no need to store in a temporary.  Just `return r;`.  You also have a potential memory leak, since you threw away the pointer allocated for `r` that is necessary for deletion.  I would have expected that you had a `string` constructor that takes a character pointer and a length, and all you would have to do is `return string(chars + i, rlength);` without need to allocate memory in this function (which again, looks like a memory leak).

Comment: Code not really sufficient.   It uses a variable `length`, but there is no information about how `length` is initialised.   Also `"This is a test".substring(0, 4) ` is not valid code.   Try providing ACTUAL code, in the form of a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem, as distinct from paraphrasing the description and leaving information out.     Odds are, that the problem is nul termination (or lack thereof).   The function you have shown does not add a trailing `'\0'` to the string, but other code probably ASSUMES such a terminator is present, and malfunctions when it is absent.

Comment: *everything else in the string class works beautifully* -- I will bet that there are issues with your class, you just haven't noticed them due to undefined behavior or other issue.  The memory leak issue is just one of them -- if you allocate memory like this in other places, without recording the pointer value so that a subsequent `delete []` is issued, then that is not "working beautifully".

Comment: As a suggestion, please look at some of the constructors available for `std::string`.  One of them is one that I have mentioned before `string(const char *, int)`, where you take a pointer to an existing string and a length, starting from that pointer.  That is exactly what you're missing here -- add that constructor to your attempt of creating a string class, and all of those issues in your code you posted go away.  No need to allocate for `r`, just make sure that the starting index is valid, the length is valid, and then a simple `return string(chars + i, rlength);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you did not provide the code for `string(char*)` constructor, the only way it could possibly tell the length of the string is by scanning for null terminator. However, character array `r` in your code lacks null termination.

Add one `char` to array's length, and set it to `'\0'` to fix this problem:

```
char* r = new char[rlength+1];
for (int i = 0 ; i < rlength ; i++) {
    r[i] = chars[i + startIndex];
}
r[rlength] = '\0';
```